# Having trouble removing a specific element from a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have been set an assignment to create a small register based program written in Java, in the form of a linked list. I started by creating a student class, and then a tester file for the class. Following that, in the registry file I have set out my methods, and a constructor, and am in the process of writing a tester file to test all my methods.

However I am having trouble when trying to remove a specific element from my linkedlist, I want to be able to remove a student, referencing them by their individual studentID, but am not sure how to do this.

Whilst trying to solve the problem I came across the `removeFirstOccurrence(Object o)` method. Is this the right method to use?

Any help would be much appreciated.

STUDENT FILE CODE:

```
public class Student {

private String foreName;
private String surName;
private int studentID;

//declaring the variables needed for my student


public Student (String foreName, String surName, int studentID)
{
    this.foreName = foreName;
    this.surName = surName;
    this.studentID = studentID;
}
//constructor to set out what a student needs



public String getForeName() {
    return foreName;
}

public String getSurName() {
    return surName;
}

public int getStudentID() {
    return studentID;
}

public void setForeName(String foreName) {
    this.foreName = foreName;
}

public void setSurName(String surName) {
    this.surName = surName;
}

public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
    this.studentID = studentID;
}

// getters and setters for my variables

public String toString ()
{

    return getClass().getName() + "foreName = " + foreName + "surName = " + surName + "studentID = " + studentID;
}
//my toString method

}
```

REGISTRY FILE CODE:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Registry {


LinkedList<String> studentList
        = new LinkedList<String>();
//setting my type parameter


public Registry() {}
//empty constructor to hold arguements

public void addStudent(String aStudent)
{
    this.studentList.addLast(aStudent);
}



public void deleteStudent(int studentID) 
{
    //????         
}


@Override public String toString()
{
  return "Registry";
}



public String format()
{
}
```

REGISTRY TESTER FILE CODE:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RegistryTester {
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    LinkedList<String> studentList
            = new LinkedList<String>();




    System.out.println("Test 1");
    System.out.println("Methods tested: addStudent, constructor");
    System.out.println("********************");

    studentList.add("Joe Perkins 123");        
    studentList.addLast("Shilpa Gupta 1234");
    studentList.addLast("Seany Ray 12345");
    // adding 3 students to my list

    System.out.println(studentList);

}

}
```

Comment: Seeing as you have a `Student` class why not use `LinkedList<Student>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define the `List` as a `List` of `Student`

   ```
   LinkedList<Student> studentList = new LinkedList<Student>();
   ```
2. Override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method in `Student` class.

   ```
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj instanceof Student) {
        return studentID == ((Student)obj).getStudentID();
      }
     return false;
   }

   public int hashCode() {
      return studentID;
   }
   ```
3. Define methods:

   ```
   public void addStudent(Student aStudent)
   {
        this.studentList.addLast(aStudent);
   }



   public void deleteStudent(Student astudent) 
   {
       this.studentList.remove(aStudent)       
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First you should make your `LinkedList`  for type `Student`:

```
LinkedList<Student>
```

Then to remove a student, you could :

- go through the list, find out the student object with same id, remove it
- override `equals() and hashcode()` method in your `Student` class, then

  ```
  public void deleteStudent(int studentID) 
  {
      //getStudent object (stu) By the given ID
      studentList.remove(stu);
  }
  ```
- use `Map`, (`HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap`) instead of `LinkedList`, key is the studentId, value is the studentObject. This will make add/remove easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Collection` (in your case a `LinkedList`) of `Student`s and call `remove(studentToRemove)` on it, Java will compare each object with `studentToRemove` by using its `equals()` method.

In your case, you haven't written an `equals()` method, hence the one for `Object` is used. If indeed a student is uniquely identified by its `studentId` (that is, two `Student` instances with the same `studentId` are always the same student) you should override the `equals()` metod and check for equality using that field.

Read about [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

Another alternative would be to iterate the list until you find the match, and then remove the student from the list.